# Axis2/c error in instalaltion

Tags: c, web-services, apache2, apache-axis, axis2c

My problem is the following one:

When installing Axis2/c under the guidance of http://petio.org/ws/web_services_page7.html , which seems to be an adjusted manual from the official site I have a problem right after executing the make command in terminal.
At exactly this point:

```
$ cd /tmp/axis/axis2c-src-1.6.0
$ ./configure --prefix=${AXIS2C_HOME} --enable-libxml2=yes
$ make
```

I get this error:

```
XXX@XXXPC:~/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0'
Making all in util
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util'
Making all in src
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util/src'
Making all in platforms/unix
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util/src/platforms/unix'
/bin/bash ../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../include/platforms -I../../../include/platforms/unix    -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Werror -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE  -MT uuid_gen_unix.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uuid_gen_unix.Tpo -c -o uuid_gen_unix.lo uuid_gen_unix.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../include/platforms -I../../../include/platforms/unix -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Werror -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT uuid_gen_unix.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uuid_gen_unix.Tpo -c uuid_gen_unix.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/uuid_gen_unix.o
**uuid_gen_unix.c: In function ‘axutil_uuid_gen_v1’:
uuid_gen_unix.c:62:20: error: variable ‘tv’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]**
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [uuid_gen_unix.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util/src/platforms/unix'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util/src'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0/util'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/Tools/axis2c/axis2c-src-1.5.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not able to understand the reason why this error is being produced.

Because 1.6.0 version is down, I am using the 1.5.0 source version of axis2/c from the official site : http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/download.cgi .

I have additionally installed Apache2 and libxml2, OpenSSL, cURL, libiconv, and zlib.
 libraries.

I need your help because I am trying to build a serious project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to mirror of original **Axis2/C-1.6.0 source distribution** is [here](http://www.sai.msu.su/apache/ws/axis2/c/1_6_0/axis2c-src-1.6.0.tar.gz).

The **main problem** is with `-Werror` flag.

To compile original Axis2/C with modern compiler you must remove `-Werror` string from build scripts. To do that run this command after unpacking tarball:

```
find -type f -name configure -exec sed -i '/CFLAGS/s/-Werror//g' {} \;
```

Then configure and make Axis2/C.

**Note:** Original Axis2/C-1.6.0 has many issues like [memory leaks](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/MemoryLeaksFixed) and crashes. Consider using [Axis2/C unofficial project](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial) instead. Most critical Axis2/C-1.6.0's [issues is fixed](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/IssuesList) within that project.

Also it have additional features https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/IssuesList like JSON support and enhanced CURL-based transport authentication (and some other features).

There is an manual on [how to install Axis2/C unofficial on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/wiki/InstallationManualLinux).

Comment: I am going with unofficial too loentar. Thanks for your anwser and for the command you provided. It seems right.